# Use the date time in the timezone of the record owner on custom object

Tags: formula, datetime, timezone

I have a custom object `My_Object__c`.

I want to build a Formula Checkbox field where the checkbox is checked if the CreatedDate local time in the Timezone of the Owner was more than 6 pm.

E.g. we have a user In California and a user in London.

I want the `My_Checkbox__c` to be checked if it was > 6 pm in California for Cali user, and > 6 pm for London user on their corresponding records.

Is that possible?

Comment: You will be better off using apex to determine the timezone and check the checkbox as you need to keep into account the timezones. This is what salesforce recommends 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&type=5

Comment: Yes, I understand I can do it with Apex but i have a few hundred thousand historical records like this and several thousands created daily, writing Apex to update history + do it as a trigger on update/create is a bit more effort that I was hoping to avoid